# parsing by cookie result sequence of weird things

Tags: node.js, request, cheerio

```
var request = require('request'),
cheerio = require('cheerio');

var i 

for(i=1; i<908; i++){

var options = {
url:k,
var address='http://gallog.dcinside.com/inc/_mylog.php? 
gid=chermy018&oneview=Y&cid=59&page=';
var k = address+'i';

request(options, function (err, response, body) {
console.log(body);
});
}
```

**error**
[image]
i selected parsing method by using cookie. if i run this code for one page, it work well, but for multiple pages it result sequence of weird symbols or letters like above. what cause this and how can i correct error? and because i only searched and modified nodejs codes for parsing, i don't know much well about cheerio. i want to parse texts but i don't know how designate under 'id' part.

Comment: Maybe the website is detecting too fast consecutive requests and sends this to annoy the scraper

Comment: as you say maybe it's too fast and annoy the scraper, i used setTimeout function and i set setTimeout run codes by 1 second. but i received undefined message which seems look like have same number of pages.

Comment: I've just tried visiting the link you're scraping, it seems that it's in Korean so you maybe try to put the contents of `body` into a file instead of outputing it directly in the console then open it with a text editor that supports utf-8 you might find a more explicit message in korean